# getting [modified] in ios notification title when adding image key

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, push-notification

I am getting [modified] in the title of ios device notification when the image parameter is added in the notification payload. Also, I tried to send a notification from firebase but got the same issue when adding an image.

Note: It is working fine in android deveice.

Ex:
If I set the title "Hello" then it shows "Hello [modified]" in ios notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "[modified]" string seems to be added based on this example `NotificationService.m` file in the [documentation for sending images in iOS FCM notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-image):

```objectivec
    @interface NotificationService () <NSURLSessionDelegate>
    @property(nonatomic) void (^contentHandler)(UNNotificationContent *contentToDeliver);
    @property(nonatomic) UNMutableNotificationContent *bestAttemptContent;
    @end
    
    @implementation NotificationService
    
    - (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
        self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];
    
        // Modify the notification content here as you wish
        self.bestAttemptContent.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ [modified]",
        self.bestAttemptContent.title];
    
      // Call FIRMessaging extension helper API.
      [[FIRMessaging extensionHelper] populateNotificationContent:self.bestAttemptContent
                                                withContentHandler:contentHandler];
    
    }
    ...
```

**Solution:**

Open your iOS project with XCode and open the `NotificationService.m` file and remove this line:

```objectivec
        // Modify the notification content here as you wish
        self.bestAttemptContent.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ [modified]",
        self.bestAttemptContent.title];
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the NotificationService file and look the code

```
 bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title) [modified] "
```

and just remove [modified] from this like this code

```
bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title) "
```

and then run again